# Set and clone works differently

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have some doubts about Set and clone on Three js, im trying to render a scene where a sphere moves trought x axis and the camera follow the move with the lookAt, i tryed to do by myself the example on the book learning three js, but i didnt used the clone and my scene did the same but i couldnt see the sphere, with the clone i could see the sphere can someone explain me why that happen??

**here is the 2 different codes:**

```
sphere.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(x,10,0));


sphere.position.set(new THREE.Vector3(x,10,0));
```

the first shows the sphere the second not :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position is `THREE.Vector3`

look at [reference](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3)
and [implementation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js)

`Vector3.set` takes 3 values : numbers `x`,`y` and `z`

`Vector3.copy` takes `Vector3`

Comment: i know about that, but if i increment the x axis i cant see my sphere with the Vector3.set, but with the vector3.copy i can

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on what Derte said already - `set` basically works like

```
function set(_x,_y,_z){
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.z = _z;
}
```

whereas `copy` works like:

```
function copy(v3){
    this.x = v3.x;
    this.y = v3.y;
    this.z = v3.z;
}
```

you're passing innapropriate parameters to the `set` function, so it is throwing an error internally in all likelyhood. hit `ctrl+shift+i` in chrome to check the console, and you'll probably see that after it executes the first line fine with `copy`, it's throwing an error when you try to do `set` with `(THREE.Vector3)` as arguments instead of `(float,float,float)`